# Create simple query using MongoDB with Yii2 advanced template

Tags: mysql, mongodb, yii2-advanced-app

How can i **build query like this in Yii2 and MongoDB**:

this is with **Yii2 and MySQL**:

```
$connection = new Query;
$sql = "SELECT e.emp_id as emp_id, e.full_name as full_name, e.email as email, e.contact as contact, e.address as address, e.gender as gender, e.avatar as avatar, e.status as status, date_format(e.added_date_time,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as added_date_time, d.dept_name as dept_name FROM employee e, department d WHERE e.dept_id = d.dept_id";
$model = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$posts = $model->queryAll();
return json_encode($posts);
```

But how can i create same query in **MongoDB with Yii2**? 
Is there any command like **createCommand()** and pass sql in that function?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to create model extended from `yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord`.

Why not to use framework features such as `ActiveRecord` and `ActiveQuery` instead of writing raw SQL?

You can write query as regular `ActiveQuery`:

```
use app\models\Employee;
use yii\db\Expression;

...

Employee::find()
    ->select([
        'emp_id',
        'full_name'
        'email',
        'contact'
        'address',
        'gender',
        'avatar',
        'status',
        'added_date_time' => new Expression("date_format(added_date_time,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')"),
        'dept_name',
    ])
    ->all();
```

Some notes about the query:

**1)** It's better to create another model for `Department` and relation if it's needed. Current selection from two tables and where condition doesn't make sense because all employees will be returned.

**2)** Because of **1)**, aliases are redundant.

**3)** Most of the times with `ActiveRecord` you don't need to explicitly specify selected attributes.

**4)** Probably it's better to format date on server side.

Comment: i added where condition because i also want department name

Comment: how can i get department name without where condition?

Comment: Use [relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data) instead.

Comment: do you know is there any relations concept in mongoDB?

Comment: and it should be in mongodb not in mysql